# How do I assign lines from an input file to an array of a class value?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, fileinputstream

What i want to do is assign each line of my input file to an array value. Since the array is of the Song[] type I'm not sure how to do this.

```
public int readMusicCollection(Song[] array, String filename) {
    int count = 0;
    Scanner inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot open input file: " + filename);
    }

    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        array[count] = inputStream.nextLine();
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: How look like the code of `Song` class? Could you put it here?

Comment: A String (what you get by nextLine) cannot be assigned to a Song[] array element. *You* must know how a line represents a Song object, and *you* must write code to create a Song from a String.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to read each line of the file and convert it to a song:

```
public static List<Song> readMusicCollection(String filename) {
    List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(new File(filename).toPath());
    // convert to Song:
    List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>(allLines.size());
    for(String line : allLines) {
        Song song = // convert line to Song
        songs.add(song);
    }
    return songs;
}
```

Using Java 8:

```
List<Song> songs = 
    Files.lines(new File(filename).toPath())
         .map(line -> transformToSong(line))   // TODO: implement transformToSong
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```